# iOS: How to swap views for autorotation using storyboards?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, orientation, autorotate

**Disclaimer**: I'm relatively new to iOS.

I'm trying to set up autorotation in my app via separate portrait and landscape views, but I'm not sure where to start. *In Beginning iOS 5 Development: Exploring the iOS SDK*, I read that this is possible by duplicating the view in the XIB, but I'm using storyboard files, not directly using XIB files.

How does one swap views for autorotation using storyboards in iOS6?

Comment: best practice #1: don't use the Xcode tag for questions that are unrelated to Xcode.

Comment: Apologies. I figured that the storyboard aspect did relate to Xcode specifically.

Comment: So... any thoughts as to the actual question?

Comment: @userXXX you can have a look at the `shouldAutorotate` method of `UIViewController`.